# Log analysis software

Tags: logs

In order to learn more about what is logged by my desktop machine, I'd like to set up something better than a casual `grep` command to see what's going on. A typical use case would be to send an email with a warning if more than *X* SSH login attempts failed within *Y* minutes for user *username*.

To be clear, this is **not for web server logs**, which most *nix log analysis tools seem to be focusing on. Also, I would like this system to be *live*, not just a `grep` in `cron`, in order to be able to catch events like `shutdown now` before the machine goes down.

[LogSurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/) *might* be the right thing for me, but I'd like to know of other, similar tools if there are any.

Of course, I'm only interested in FLOSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **[logwatch](http://www.logwatch.org/)** is a common solution for log analysing and monitoring
- **[logsentry](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sentrytools/)** is also a classic package, targeted mainly at security

(Don't be put off by the lacks of shiny websites - many well-established, BSD-derived tools just *aren't trying* to promote themselves - it's enough for them to be known by experts.)

Comment: Looks like `logwatch` is meant to be run "after the fact". Is it possible to plug this into the live syslog stream?

Comment: Looks like the [Logcheck part of `logsentry`](http://logcheck.org/) has moved; the SourceForge tarball is from 2003.

Comment: Looks like `logcheck` has to be run periodically, and can't run live because `logtail` doesn't take input from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

We use [SEC](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/) at my current job. It's functionally similar to LogSurfer, in that it watches log files in real time ("tail -f" style), and it can act on any arbitrary event or combination of events. Like LogSurfer, you match the lines you're interested in using regular expressions, so you aren't limited to a particular log format.

Another one I ran across while looking for a link for SEC is [LoGS](http://www.hpc.unm.edu/~download/LoGS/). I've never seen or used it, but if you're in the evaluation stage, if might be worth a look, too.